# javascript function not working in other file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, function

I have a HTML-page where I include all of my js.files in the head

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/addtab.css">
            //some more
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tab_menu.css">

    <script src="js/addtab.js"></script>
    //some more
    <script src="js/tab_menu.js"></script>
</head>
```

and in the addtab.js I declare a function, I want to use there and in the tab_menu.js:

addtab.js:

```
function addTab (a=null, b=null) {
     //doing Stuff 
}
```

tab_menu.js:

```
;$(function() {

    tabs.delegate( "div.copier", "click", function() {
        //doing stuff

        addtab(title, descryption);

        //doing stuff
    }); 
});
```

but I get that:

```
ReferenceError: addtab is not defined
```

Edit: Okay.. it was just a typo, but thanks to the others that you pointed out a mistake I haven't noticed yet^^
So that I can solve them at a stroke...

Comment: @SridharR — That can't be the problem. It is complaining about `addtab` not `$`.

Comment: `function addTab (a=null, b=null) {` change it to function `addTab (a, b)`

Comment: [Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters) are supported by FF only.

Comment: @Teemu I'm programming and testing first in FF, so that's why he doesn't complaint about that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function addTab (a=null, b=null) {` is not valid JS.

You can't assign values to augments in the function declaration.

It should be:

```
function addTab(a, b) {
```

You **should** have got an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =` error before the error you reported.

---

Then you try to call `addtab` when the function is called `addTab`. JavaScript identifiers are case sensitive.

Answer (score 5):

You define `addTab` but call `addtab`.  Javascript function names are case sensitive.